# Scroll bar to custom ViewGroup

Tags: android, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview, viewgroup

I have `CustomComponent`  class which extends `ViewGroup`.

Source code of `CustomComponent`:

```
      public class CustomComponent extends ViewGroup {

            private static final String LOGTAG = "CustomComponent";

            private List<MenuItem> items;

            private Context context;

            private int screenWidth;
            private int screenHeight;
            private int cellWidth;
            private int cellHeight;
            private int duration;
        private int space=7;

       public CustomComponent(Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.context=context;
       }


             @Override
          protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            Log.v(LOGTAG, "on Measure called");
             screenWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
              screenHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
              cellHeight=screenHeight/AppConstants.HEIDHTCELLSCOUNT;
              cellWidth=screenWidth/AppConstants.WIDTHCELLSCOUNT;
              duration= cellHeight*2;
             super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec+duration);

          }


           @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            Log.v(LOGTAG, "onLayout called");
            int childCount = this.getChildCount();
                 for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                      View child = getChildAt(i);
                          child.layout(items.get(i).getLeft(),items.get(i).getTop(),items.get(i).getRight(), items.get(i).getBottom());
        } 
      }

public List<MenuItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<MenuItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
    }
```

Xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
        <<package name>.CustomComponentandroid:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_component"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to add vertical scroll to this `ViewGroup`.
Please help, I have no idea how to solve this problem. 
[image]

Comment: The code from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-masonry/source/checkout) worked for me you may need some editing to suit yours

Comment: Hi Natali, I know this question is too old but did you get solution to this. If you have got it plz post it. I am stuck in similar situation

Comment: Hello. I did not find any solution for it, so I used Relative Layout with Custom Views (colored boxes) as child views.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. You need a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. Put your MenuComponent inside the LinearLayout. It should work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <<package name>.MenuComponent android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/menu_component"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same 'balack screen'. :(

Comment: No, I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to include your `MenuComponent` inside a `ScrollView`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
      <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <<package name>.MenuComponent android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/menu_component"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical"/>
       </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I try this before ask this question, but whith this xml I have the black screen. My viev grout is created but unfortunately it's not shown.

Comment: Could you add more info about your problem? what do you want to achieve with your custom MenuComponent? What errors are you getting?

Comment: I added scheme of my component. I need add scroll down ny `ViewGroup` to  the `duration` size.

Comment: Do you need to use that custom component? I would suggest using a `RelativeLayout` (container) inside a `ScrollView` and inflate each item inside the container

Comment: Thank for your council. I will think adout it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `awakenScrollBars()` ,which will trigger the scrollbars to draw on your custom viewGroup.([more details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#awakenScrollBars%28%29)) and the vertical scrollbar enabled has to be true `setVerticalScrollBarEnabled()`

Also you have to override functions `computeVerticalScrollExtent()` and `computeVerticalScrollRange` to set thumb's size and scrollbar scroll range .